# Reading a Registry Key C++

Tags: c++, registry

First of all, I'm expecting my issue to be easily fixed and I'm sorry for this but I can't get it to work.

So this is my code (taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724235(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LONG lResult;
    HKEY hKey;
    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Test"), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("Key not found.\n");

        }
        else {
            printf("Error opening key.\n");

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the message "Key not found" but I have created a key called "Test" under HKLM\SOFTWARE and I run Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: Is "Test" a key or a value? `RegOpenKeyEx` only opens keys (which are like folders), to read a value from an opened key you should use `RegQueryValueEx`.

Comment: "Test" is a key. Inside it, I have a string value  Value1(REG_SZ)="testvalue"

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @melak47 So, I assume it's not code related...

Comment: Possibly permission related, try running your program as admin to see if you can read it then?

Comment: I'm already doing that and it's still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105446/discussion-between-melak47-and-lerul-ler).